# $|f(z)| \leq M|z|^n$, then $f$ is a polynomial of degree $\leq n$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be an entire function and suppose there is a constant $M$, and an integer $n \geq 1 $ such that $|f(z)| \leq M|z|^n $ for large $|z|$. Show that $f$ is a polynomial of degree $ \leq n$.

Comment: Okay, I edited the title

Comment: **Hints without spoilers:** Liouville's theorem or Cauchy's estimate

Answer (score 5):

**Hint** Let $g(z)=f(z)-f(0)-\frac{f'(0)}{1!}z-..-\frac{f^{(n-1)}(0)}{(n-1)!}z^n$.

Prove that $\frac{g(z)}{z^n}$ has a removable discontinuity at $0$, and its continuation is entire and bounded.

Comment: How does the function g(z)/(z^n) become entire?

Comment: @BijanDatta Well, it is easy to prove that $g/z^n$ is differentiable at $z \neq 0$, and $g/z^n$ has a Taylor series at $z=0$, thus it is differentiable..